# Iterate Over List and Deduct Random Value from Time Values

Tags: python, namedtuple

I have a long list of `NamedTuples` which contain time values. Extract below. I want to iterate over the list and deduct a random value from each time value. ie a different random number for each time value.

The problem is that sometimes the random value deducted results in a `sleep length must be non-negative` error.

How can I first test whether the result of the random value deduction would lead to a negative number and skip deducting the random value from that particular time value?

List extract:

```
list_one = [Test(a=820, b=625, time=1643282249.9990437), Test(a=820, b=624, time=1643282250.0470896), Test(a=820, b=623, time=1643282250.1034527), Pass(test_type='do1', pass='ffg3', time=1643282250.7834597)]
```

Code:

```
randomise = lambda: random.randint(-5, 5)
randomise_time = lambda: random.uniform(0.01, 0.001)
list_one = [Test(t.a + randomise(), t.b + randomise(), t.time - randomise_time()) if isinstance(t, Test) else t for t in list_one]
```

Comment: Not really sure what you mean to do here, but I think you can determine the randint range with the time value so that the minimum of the randint range will be `-<time value>`. Let me know if it helps

Comment: what is the code behind the 'Test' and the 'Pass' classes??

Comment: This code doesn't reproduce the issue. I believe you are calling time.sleep(-1) somewhere. That makes sense because you are subtracting times, but there is no "sleep" in the code you posted. The traceback should tell you where that was. As Omer already mentioned, you need to pay attention to the actual values when you subtract "random" amounts.